# TFHub Embedding feature column in Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I can't figure out how to use the Tensorflow Hub embedding column (`hub.text_embedding_column`) in a Keras model converted to a `tf.Estimator`.

Using the embedding in a Keras model is achievable if I do not convert the model to an estimator.

For example, with some dummy data defined as so:

```
x_train = ['the quick brown fox', 'jumps over a lazy']
x_eval = ['the quick brown fox', 'jumps over a lazy']
y_train = [0, 1]
y_eval = [0, 1]
```

Then, I can use the following code to train a keras model without errors

```
embed = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1')
def _embed(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))

# workaround for keras
x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]
x_eval = np.array(x_eval, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]

input_text = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(_embed, output_shape=(128,))(input_text)
pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(x_eval, y_eval))
```

However, if I try to convert it to an estimator using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`, all of a sudden I cannot train the model anymore.

```
embedding = hub.text_embedding_column('text', 'https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1')
features = {'text': x_train}
labels = y_train[:, np.newaxis]

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(features, labels, shuffle=False)

embedding_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), dtype=tf.float32, name='text')
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='logits')(embedding_input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=embedding_input, outputs=logits)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)

estimator.train(input_fn, max_steps=1)
```

If I use a canned estimator like `tf.estimator.DNNEstimator`, I can train a model as well without errors.

```
embedding = hub.text_embedding_column('text', 'https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1')
features = {'text': x_train}
labels = y_train[:, np.newaxis]

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(features, labels, shuffle=False)
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier([32], [embedding])
```

The error I got when I tried to train it with the keras model converted to estimator is:

```
Input 0 of layer logits is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]
```

The full stack trace is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f1d8a31726e2> in <module>()
     22 estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
     23 
---> 24 estimator.train(input_fn, max_steps=1)

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    374 
    375       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 376       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    377       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    378       return self

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1143       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1144     else:
-> 1145       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1146 
   1147   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1168       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1169       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1170           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1171       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
   1172                                              hooks, global_step_tensor,

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1131 
   1132     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1133     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1134     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1135 

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/keras.pyc in model_fn(features, labels, mode)
    357     """model_fn for keras Estimator."""
    358     model = _clone_and_build_model(mode, keras_model, custom_objects, features,
--> 359                                    labels)
    360     model_output_names = []
    361     # We need to make sure that the output names of the last layer in the model

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/keras.pyc in _clone_and_build_model(mode, keras_model, custom_objects, features, labels)
    313         model = models.clone_model(keras_model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
    314     else:
--> 315       model = models.clone_model(keras_model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
    316   else:
    317     model = keras_model

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.pyc in clone_model(model, input_tensors)
    261     return _clone_sequential_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
    262   else:
--> 263     return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.pyc in _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors)
    154               kwargs['mask'] = computed_mask
    155           output_tensors = generic_utils.to_list(layer(computed_tensor,
--> 156                                                        **kwargs))
    157           output_masks = generic_utils.to_list(
    158               layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor, computed_mask))

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    718 
    719         # Check input assumptions set before layer building, e.g. input rank.
--> 720         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    721         if input_list and self._dtype is None:
    722           try:

.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in _assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
   1438                            ', found ndim=' + str(ndim) +
   1439                            '. Full shape received: ' +
-> 1440                            str(x.shape.as_list()))
   1441       # Check dtype.
   1442       if spec.dtype is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer logits is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]
```

Comment: Did you manage to use TFHub Embedding and keras model_to_estimator successfully?

Comment: No I have not - I've managed to rewrite the model using the functions in tf.layers instead, returning an EstimatorSpec and then creating an Estimator from there, but I could not get the same performance from it and I haven't managed to figure out why yet.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to figure out how to use `model_to_estimator` with a TFHub embedding. You'll need to do the embedding outside of the Keras model. Your Keras model would have to take the embeddings as input, instead of processing the embedding within the model. However, you can use the Keras model as a function within an estimator function.

For instance, you can define a Keras model which accepts the pre-computed embedding (for this example, I wanted to have the embedding return a sequence rather than a single averaged embedding, so the input shape has a sequence length):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import shutil

def create_model(max_seq_len, embedding_size):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, input_shape=(max_seq_len, embedding_size)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv1D(8, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

Instead of compiling this model and then using `model_to_estimator`, you will define an estimator model function, e.g.:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):

    model = create_model(5, 128)

    embed = hub.Module(...)
    text_seq = pad_seq(features['text'], 5)
    embeddings = tf.map_fn(embed, text_seq)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        logits = model(embeddings, training=True)

     # some more logic
```

Calling the Keras model like this gives you the computed logits from the model. You can then return a `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` to create an Estimatorm abd then train from there.

You can refer to [the Tensorflow MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist.py) to see how they wrap Tensorflow computations around a Keras model to create the estimator model function and then the estimator, even though they are not using anything from TFHub.